# Dynamically Populate All Sheets in Excel Workbook to a Master Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a workbook with multiple sheets. All contain the same columns but just different categorical data. I want to grab all the data from those sheets and display/populate to a master sheet in the workbook.

I have tried different methods, but none of them are dynamic. The amount of data can be changed (+/-, either more rows or less rows) in each sheet. Each method I have found seems to be a static solution.

One example is to use the Consolidate option under the data tab, and add the respective reference/range for each sheet you would like to add (not dynamic).

Another option I found was a VBA macro, which populates the headers over and over, which I do not want to happen either, I want them all under the same header (Since the columns are already the same)

```
Sub Combine()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20180205
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Combined"
   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange
        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If
        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
    Next
End Sub
```

Is this achievable?

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Master Sheet Should Be:

[image]

But actually returns the following:

[image]

Will this constantly run each time the workbook is closed/opened/updated if it is a macro enabled workbook?

Comment: Are you trying to copy `xRg` to `Sheet(1)`? or is `xRg` supposed to be where you copy to? note: you will also need to paste what you have copied. Side note: You should remove `On error resume next` it hides any problems the code may have.

Comment: Updated question. xRg is supposed to be where I copy to

Comment: I would use Power Query rather than VBA for this. Click in first your first table and on the Data tab hit From Table/Range. When the window pops up close and load, then repeat for the second table. In the Queries & Collections bar right click either table and select append. Select both instead of close and load click the arrow and select close and load to. Change to existing worksheet and select where you want it. Use refresh to update the table after changes are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consolidate All Worksheets

- It is assumed that the `Combined` worksheet already exists with at least the headers which will stay intact.
- To make it more efficient, only values are copied (no formats or formulas).
- It will utilize the `Worksheet Activate event`: each time you activate (select) the combined worksheet, the data will automatically be updated.

**Sheet Module of the `Combined` worksheet e.g. `Sheet10(Combined)`**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    CombineToMaster
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CombineToMaster()
    
    Const dName As String = "Combined"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim drrg As Range
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Set drrg = .Offset(1)
        Else
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).Clear
            Set drrg = .Resize(1).Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If sws.Name <> dName Then
            With sws.UsedRange
                rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
                If rCount > 0 Then
                    Set srg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
                    drrg.Resize(rCount).Value = srg.Value
                    Set drrg = drrg.Offset(rCount)
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next sws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer! I tried updating one sheet to see if it would auto update, and it did not update the combined sheet. I went in and ran it (F5) again, and it updated it but I would like it to be able to auto update

Comment: Have you copied the short code to the correct place, to the sheet module of worksheet `Combined`? You haven't shared the purpose of the combined worksheet. If you plan on using it to perform calculations on it you previously need to run the code to update it. If you just want to look at it, it is enough to select it and it will automatically be updated (you cannot see a not updated version unless you disable events). If you have accidentally disabled events, you can enable them with the line `Application.EnableEvents = True` or check the status with e.g. `MsgBox Application.EnableEvents`.

Comment: Confsed what you mean by sheet module, I had the worksheet selected --> Alt + F11 --> Inserted the module and copy and pasted the short code

Comment: So I opened the VBAProject, double clicked Sheet9 (Combined) and posted the short code in there, saved and ran. Then created Module1, and pasted the longer code in there. After both were saved and ran, only code from the first sheet was posted to combined, nothing else

Comment: Disregard previous comment, So I did this, and it creates a bunch of white spaces and carries over the empty rows from other sheets? Any fix

Comment: Feel free to download the working file from [my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eSakHnak_fRRcM_D4fZ-tmXhU_ljuVVn/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

#### VBA Solution

```
Sub Combine()
    
    Dim wsCombine  As Worksheet: Set wsCombine = GetSheetCombine
    Dim dataSheets As Collection: Set dataSheets = GetDataSheets
    
    ' Copy Header
    dataSheets.Item(1).UsedRange.Rows(1).Copy
    wsCombine.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    wsCombine.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Copy data
    Dim rngDest As Range: Set rngDest = wsCombine.Range("A2")
    Dim srcRng  As Range
    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In dataSheets
        ' Drop header row
        With ws.UsedRange
            Set srcRng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With
        srcRng.Copy rngDest
        Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(srcRng.Rows.Count)
    Next ws
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Private Function GetSheetCombine() As Worksheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = .Item("Combine")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Set ws = .Add(Before:=.Item(1))
            ws.Name = "Combine"
        Else
            ws.Cells.Clear ' clear any existing data
        End If
    End With
    Set GetSheetCombine = ws
    
End Function

Private Function GetDataSheets() As Collection

    Dim Result As New Collection
    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Combine" Then Result.Add ws
    Next ws
    Set GetDataSheets = Result
    
End Function
```

---

**As to your question** "Will this run every time macro enabled workbook is open?".

No. You will need to put this in a VBA module and run it every time you need, via the Macro dialog (View->Macros), or link a button to it.

Comment: "Will this run every time macro enabled workbook is open?". a 3rd option: Call it when the workbook opens or before close by using [events](https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/)